# Fill enum from database

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, enums

let say I have class called product [entity class] which have a nested enum looks like

```
Class product () {
private String id;
// other attributes

public enum Type {

        G1(false, false, false, false),
        G2(false, false, ture, false),
        G3(false, false, false, true),
}
private Type type = Type.G3;

//constructors, setters, getters and other methods.
}
```

I have a new requirement as Type may changes or new types will be added. we will create a new table called ProductType. so I need to fill enum type from that table when server starts.

note : I am not able to change enum to object because it's a legacy code and that enum is used in many places in the app.
I'm using java.

any Ideas?

I have tried to use object instead of enum but many problems happend.

Comment: Not sure what the question is here but don't use `Type` (it's already reserved)

Comment: NO it's not in java. may be in other langs

Comment: Are you saying that there may be more elements in `Type`, for example you may need to add a `G4` element?

Comment: More accurately I should say it's [already a type name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Type.html)

Comment: If you are loading from a dB and want the enum to be dynamic, don't use an enum. Use a normal class, since enums are static.

Comment: the problem is that I can't change that enum because I will need to change many many class which use that enum

Answer (score 0):

Your code has syntax mistakes (if it's Java).

You can not do that one with an enum, because it's a static "set" of instances of type - `Type`.

I guess your `Type` has methods which are used by different parts of an application. I would start refactoring from replacing the word `enum` to `class` (with a constructor parameter `productTypeId` - ID in DB), remove G1, G2, G3 from `class`, redefine old methods which return attributes from DB, etc.